# ICMP timestamps added to ping echo requests in linux. How are they represented to bytes? Or how to convert UNIX Epoch time to that timestamp format?

Tags: linux, unix, networking, timestamp, ping

I encountered this issue while trying to make a ping program in C myself and used wireshark for further digging into the problem: ping which sends echo requests to a destination IP also ads a timestamp field of 8 bytes (TOD timestamp) after the ICMP header in linux. Ping in Windows doesn't add that timestamp but rather I think makes the time calculations locally. Now my question is how do you convert the time from Unix Epoch format (the number of seconds from 1970 which you get with the 'time' function in C) to that TOD format of 8 bytes? I got to this question as, finally, after quite a time of research, my ping.c program sends the ICMP echo request message to the destination, where after a test with 2 hosts I noticed that it manages to arrive, but gets no ping echo reply message back while the native linux ping works properly. I can only imagine 2 possible causes:

1. I didnt complete well the fields of the ICMP and IP header. To be honest, I myself pretty much doubt this possiblity because wireshark shows the message arrives to the destination and is recognized as an echo request message, but doesn't trigger any echo reply answer. However, if it would to be this, the only thing I can think off is that timestamp which I don`t know how to convert in TOD form to occupy at most 8 bytes.
2. There might be a firewall at the destination or some other system dependent fact.

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.2.0?topic=problems-using-ping-command

> The Ping command does not use the ICMP/ICMPv6 header sequence number field (icmp_seq or icmp6_seq) to correlate requests with ICMP/ICMPv6 Echo Replies. Instead, it uses the ICMP/ICMPv6 header identifier field (icmp_id or icmp6_id) plus an 8-byte TOD time stamp field to correlate requests with replies. The TOD time stamp is the first 8-bytes of data after the ICMP/ICMPv6 header.

Finally, to repeat the initial question:
*How do you convert the UNIX Epoch time to the TOD timestamp form which linux ping adds at the end of the ICMP header/begining of data field?*

An useful explanation, but I don't think sufficient I found here:
https://towardsdatascience.com/3-tips-to-handle-timestamps-in-c-ad5b36892294

I should probably mention I`m working on Ubuntu 20.04 focalfossa.

I found a related post here. The book "Principles of Operation" is mentioned in the comments. I skimmed through it but it seems to be generally lower level than C so if anyone knows another place/way to answer the question it would be better.

Comment: First note that ICMP is a whole range of possible messages, there is not just one case. The core document is RFC792 but then other ones do change things and deprecate some cases, etc. If you are talking about the timestamp case, the value is explained as such in the document: "The timestamp is 32
      bits of milliseconds since midnight UT."  If you are talking about the "
Echo or Echo Reply Message" there is no timestamp there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I asked my own question below because there is a fixed limit of characters for these comments and I needed more space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Background

Including the UNIX timestamp of the time of transmission in the first data bytes of the ICMP Echo message is a trick/optimization [the original `ping`](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/BSD-4_3/usr/src/etc/ping.c#L233) by Mike Muuss used to avoid keeping track of it locally. It exploits the following guarantee made by [RFC 792](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc792.html)'s *Echo or Echo Reply Message* description:

> The data received in the echo message must be returned in the echo reply message.

Many (if not all) BSD `ping` implementations are based on Mike Muuss' original implementation and therefore kept this behavior. On Linux systems, `ping` is typically provided by [`iputils`](https://github.com/iputils/iputils/blob/20211215/ping/ping.c#L1444), [GNU `inetutils`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/inetutils.git/tree/ping/ping.c#n504), or [Busybox](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/networking/ping.c?h=1_35_0#n571). All exhibit the same behavior. [`fping`](https://github.com/schweikert/fping/blob/v5.1/src/seqmap.h) is a notable exception, which stores a mapping from target host and sequence number to timestamp locally.

Implementations typically store the timestamp in the sender's native precision and byte order as opposed to a well-defined precision in conventional network byte order (big endian), that is normally used for data transmitted over the network, as it intended to be only be interpreted by the original sender and others should just treat it as opaque stream of bytes.

Because this is so common however, the [Wireshark ICMP dissector](https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/blob/v3.6.2/epan/dissectors/packet-icmp.c#L1720) (as of v3.6.2) tries to be clever and heuristically decode it nonetheless, if the first 8 data bytes look like a `struct timeval` timestamp in 32-bit precision for seconds and microseconds in either byte order. Please note that if the sender was actually using big endian 64-bit precision, this will fail and if it was using little endian 64-bit precision, it will truncate the microseconds before the [Epochalypse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) and fail after that.

## Obtaining and serializing epoch time

To answer your actual question:

> *How do you convert the UNIX Epoch time to the TOD timestamp form which linux ping adds at the end of the ICMP header/begining of data field?*

Most implementations use the obsolescent [`gettimeofday(2)`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/gettimeofday.html) instead of the newer [`clock_gettime(2)`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_gettime.html). The following snippet is taken from `iputils`:

```
struct icmphdr *icp /* = pointer to ICMP packet */;
struct timeval tmp_tv;
gettimeofday(&tmp_tv, NULL);
memcpy(icp + 1, &tmp_tv, sizeof(tmp_tv));
```

[`memcpy`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/memcpy.html) from a temporary variable instead of directly passing the `icp + 1` as target to `gettimeofday` is used to avoid potential improper alignment, effective type and strict aliasing violation [issues](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/object).

Comment: Quite an exhaustive answer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the clear answers. I actually managed to solve the problem and make the ping function work and I have to say the problem was certainly not the timestamp because, yes indeed, i was talking about the "Echo or Echo Reply Message". One way of implementing ping is by using the ICMP feature of Echo and Echo reply messages. The fact is when I put this question I was obviously stuck probably because I wasn't clearly differentiating the main aspects of the problem. Thus, I started to examine the packet sent by the native ping on my Ubuntu 20.04 focal_fossa (with Wireshark), hopefully trying to get a better grasp of how to fill the headers of the packet sent by my program (the IP and ICMP headers). This question simply arised from the fact that I noticed that in this version of Ubuntu, ping adds a timestamp (indeed of 32 bits) after the end of ICMP header, basically in the data/payload section. As a matter of fact, I also used Wireshark on Windows10 and saw that there is no timestamp added after the header. So yes, it might be about different versions of the program being used.

What is the main point I want to emphasize is that my final version of ping has nothing to do with any timestamps. So yes, they are not a crucial aspect for ping to work.

Comment: Remember that the initial purpose of ICMP Echo + Reply is: "The data received in the echo message must be returned in the echo
      reply message." So the sender puts whatever it wants in  the data part and expects to get it back to correlate.